# Show that the arc length integral is continuous in $C^1$

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I came across this question and I am not sure how to prove it.

Show that the arc length integral is continuous in $C^1$.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? The $C^1$ norm on what exactly? Presumably the space $C^1([a,b], \Omega)$ where $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$?

Comment: I assume you tried to write down $\operatorname{length}(\gamma_1)-\operatorname{length}(\gamma_2)$ as the difference of two integrals? Which can be combined into integral of the difference? Where the integrand somewhat resembles the expression we see in the Mean Value theorem?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't have room in my schedule to take a calculus of variations so I have been teaching it to myself and found this question in a textbook. I mean the norm commonly used in C^1 which measures the size of the function and its derivative

Answer (score 1):

Let $f,g$ be two $C^1$ functions on $[a,b]$.

We have
$$
\sqrt{1+f'^2}-\sqrt{1+g'^2}=\frac{f'^2-g'^2}{\sqrt{1+f'^2}+\sqrt{1+g'^2}}.
$$
So
$$
|\sqrt{1+f'^2(x)}-\sqrt{1+g'^2(x)}|\leq\frac{|f'^2(x)-g'^2(x)|}{2}\leq\frac{|f'(x)-g'(x)|(|f'(x)|+|g'(x)|)}{2}
$$
for all $x\in(a,b)$.

Now fix $f$ and take $g$ such that $\|g'-f'\|_\infty\leq 1$. Then $\|g'\|_\infty\leq 1+\|f'\|_\infty$, so
$$
|\sqrt{1+f'^2(x)}-\sqrt{1+g'^2(x)}|\leq\frac{(1+2\|f'\|_\infty)}{2}\|f'-g'\|_\infty
$$
for all $x\in(a,b)$.

Denote
$$
I(f):=\int_a^b\sqrt{1+f'^2(x)}dx
$$
the arclength function.

We have, with $f$ and $g$ as above,
$$
|I(f)-I(g)|\leq \frac{(b-a)(1+2\|f'\|_\infty)}{2}\|f'-g'\|_\infty.
$$

So $I(f)$ is locally Lipschitz with respect to $\|f'\|_\infty$. A fortiori, with respect to the usual $C^1$ norm $\|f\|_\infty+\|f'\|_\infty$.

Hence it is continuous at $f$ for all $f$ in $C^1$.